# The method withVersion(ModelVersion) in the type PredictRequest<Prediction> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, maven, clarifai

I'm new to the Clarifai. I'm trying sample demo code using java in Clarifai portal. Below is my code. I'm getting the errors. I don't have any idea. can someone please help me.

```
package com.demo.clarifia;

import java.util.List;

import clarifai2.api.ClarifaiBuilder;
import clarifai2.api.ClarifaiClient;
import clarifai2.api.ClarifaiResponse;
import clarifai2.dto.input.ClarifaiInput;
import clarifai2.dto.model.ConceptModel;
import clarifai2.dto.model.ModelVersion;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import clarifai2.dto.model.output.ClarifaiOutput;
import clarifai2.dto.prediction.Prediction;



public class TestDemo {

private static ClarifaiClient client;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //      System.err.println("Hello Maven");

    new ClarifaiBuilder("6f890249d808461a90258289f65c792f")
    .client(new OkHttpClient()) // OPTIONAL. Allows customization of OkHttp by the user
    .buildSync(); // or use .build() to get a Future<ClarifaiClient>

    ConceptModel model = client.getDefaultModels().generalModel();
    ModelVersion modelVersion = model.getVersionByID("the-version").executeSync().get();

    ClarifaiResponse<List<ClarifaiOutput<Prediction>>> response = client.predict(model.id())
        .withInputs(ClarifaiInput.forImage("http://www.google.com"))
        .withVersion("aa7f35c01e0642fda5cf400f543e7c40") //Error here
        .executeSync();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the method `withVersion` requires a parameter of type `ModelVersion`, but you gave it a `String`. So create a `ModelVersion` object from your `String`.